# Переадресация с https://www на https без www

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как через .htaccess настроить переадресацию с https://www на https без www ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему так: Создал отдельно домен с **WWW** , получил на него сертификат и в домене www через .htaccess добавил редирект

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ИМЯ_САЙТА\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ИМЯ_САЙТА.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Спустя год, по неизвестным причинам появилась ошибка при переходе на http и я сделал вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Пробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

или

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* https://ДОМЕН.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: не работает так

Comment: @l2banners, если строки - `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]` и `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` - убрать, то `www.` удалит из адреса?

Comment: Нет. у меня www домен не подписан почему-то, я так понял пока не подпишу переадресация не сработает и будет писать что сертификат не годен

Comment: После подписи  сертификата для www заработали все редиректы как надо, спасибо за ответы